# <select> HTML element with height

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know of a way to style an HTML select element so that it has a certain height and looks good across browsers?  I've tried simply setting height in CSS but the text inside the box is vertically off-center in Firefox.

```
<select style="height:1.8em;">
```

This is not a duplicate question.  The other question asks about the height of the drop-down box that appears when you click on a select element.  My question is about the height of the unclicked select element.

Comment: use `line-height`. Set the value to the height you set. For example, `line-height: 40px;`

Comment: Share the code you have already.

Comment: what element are you refering to (div, table,span,...)? can you post code ....

Comment: Sorry, the question looked idiotic before.  Formatting got me.  I cleaned it up.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I've used a few CSS hacks and targeted Chrome/Safari/Firefox/IE individually, as each browser renders selects a bit differently. I've tested on all browsers except IE.

***For Safari/Chrome***, set the `height` and `line-height` you want for your `<select />`.

***For Firefox***, we're going to *kill* Firefox's default padding and border, then set our own. Set padding to whatever you like.

***For IE 8+***, just like Chrome, we've set the `height` and `line-height` properties. These two `media queries` can be combined. But I kept it separate for demo purposes. So you can see what I'm doing.

**Please note**, for the `height/line-height` property to work in Chrome/Safari OSX, you must set the `background` to a custom value. I changed the color in my example.

Here's a jsFiddle of the below: http://jsfiddle.net/URgCB/4/

**For the non-hack route, why not use a custom select plug-in via jQuery? Check out this:** http://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ctsCz

**HTML:**

```
<select>
    <option>Here's one option</option>
    <option>here's another option</option>
</select>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {  /*safari and chrome*/
    select {
        height:30px;
        line-height:30px;
        background:#f4f4f4;
    } 
}
select::-moz-focus-inner { /*Remove button padding in FF*/ 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() { /* targets Firefox only */
    select {
        padding: 15px 0!important;
    }
}        
@media screen\0 { /* IE Hacks: targets IE 8, 9 and 10 */        
    select {
        height:30px;
        line-height:30px;
    }     
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect on the height in my tests.

Comment: Mike, can you load your jsfiddle example in Firefox?  On 24.1.1 the text is pinned to the top of the select box for me.

Comment: I see now...let me investigate.

Comment: Please see my updated post. This *should* do the trick

Comment: What a mess. :)  But that's not your fault and I appreciate your help.  I guess I'm looking for something that will work across browsers without resorting to this kind of thing.

Comment: I ain't super pretty, I assure you that. But really, the only hack is the `@-moz-document url-prefix()` and maybe the IE one. The rest is normal CSS and `media queries`...

Comment: This doesn't work but perhaps it's because the answer is a few years old. In 2016, the answer is to set the background color. This will make the height work as expected. Alternatively, you can use "-webkit-appearance: menulist-button;".

Comment: Just tested fiddle, stills works. Your "-webkit-appearance" hack will only work on Safari/Chrome. Not IE or Firefox.

Comment: Now (2019) it seems the `padding: 15px 0 !important` is not needed.  Bound to be a nicer way by now but if you need a quick fix - copy paste the above and remove the third entry (for Firefox only).

Answer (score -4):

You can also "center" the text with:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: Vertical-align only works with `tables` and `inline` elements.

Comment: @MikeBarwick The select element *is* inline

Comment: vertical-align:middle; and vertical-align:bottom; both seem to have no effect unfortunately.