# How the set height of a selection box drop down?

Tags: html

I have 2 selection boxes states and cities, On state selection change I am writing a java script to display cities of that respective state by hiding rest of the cities. The problem is, height of the selection box dropdown is getting effected in chrome where as its appearing fine in firefox.

[image: This is how its appearing in Chrome]

[image: This is how its appears in Firefox]

Is there a quick and proper solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution to this problem in this post myself
[Height of an HTML select box (dropdown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown)

maybe you can check that one out. it helped me out a lot and i hope it helps with your problem aswell.

As i just saw there is a kind of dublicate Question right here
[<select> HTML element with height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477823/select-html-element-with-height)

It got some good Ideas too. But i didnt check them all so far. Maybe you can find something in that post too

Comment: I too have gone through those solutions none of it working for me. Specially the first one, it just elaborate the way selection drop down generally works. In my case I am using Jquery to hide certain options from the selection box. Instead of hide if I use remove the dropdown is appearing fine. I guess this is a very small problem, I am not getting a proper solution for that.